# OutOfMemory error on Android 6.0.1 devices after the second launch

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

My project was working until I updated my S6 Edge to Android 6.0.1.

The app crashes with an OutOfMemory error **after** the second launch.

The application contains 2000+ images in the directory and I am using a timer to increment a counter and display them on an imageView. When onFinish()/onPause()/onDestroy() is called I am destroying/cancelling all the objects such as the timers, counter and imageView by setting them to null.

**This is how I am fetching/printing the image to the imageView**

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("animation"+i , "drawable", getPackageName());
    Drawable animationFrame = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, resID);
    animationView.setImageDrawable(animationFrame);
    i++;
```

It runs on initial launch (even if I install the app using a generated APK). When I remove the app from the minimised applications, the application crashes after 2-3 seconds. I have checked the memory allocated and it is normal (up to 12MB) on the first run whereas on the second the memory allocated is 255MB.

**onDestroy() method**
This includes **ALL** my variables initialised. My variables are initialised as private or with no access variable.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    pauseAnimation();
    animationView.setImageDrawable(null);
    animationView = null;
    justAnimation = null;
    buttonSign = null;
    i = 0;
    media.stop();
    media  = null;
    deathRateEU = 0;
    deathRateUK = 0;
    labelNumber = null;
    labelNumberUK = null;
    buttonSign = null;
    loadingEU = null;
    loadingUK = null;

}
```

*Media is a MediaPlayer initialised as public and it plays a sound when counter(i) reaches a point*

I installed this on another device that runs Android 5.1.3 (not sure but it is 5.1 something).

Is there is a known bug for OutOfMemory issues when application get minimised on Android 6.0.1?

I am 100% sure that I did not make any changes before/after my phone updated to version 6.0.1

**Memory Monitor on 1st Launch**
[image]

**Second Launch**
[image]

**Notes:**

1. If the application is already installed on the device and I try to compile it using Android Studio, the crash occurs
2. I have to uninstall/re-compile to manage to get the app working in the first go
3. I get the same error when I try to run my project on a Genymotion Android 6.0 device, but not on an Android 5.1 genymotion virtual device

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This would include the code that is crashing and the stack trace of the crash.

Comment: Out of interest, does onDestroy even get called?  I had to move some image and video related cleanup code to onPause, and restore it in onResume, because onDestroy wasn't a reliable place to do this.

Comment: Yes, I placed a breakpoint to make sure that this method is called

Comment: My question is: I am destroying all my objects properly? my project contains variables such as MediaPlayer, Animation, int(s), timers and buttons

Comment: `finish();` ??? In onDestroy() ?

Comment: that was put there just to make sure that the application will call onDestroy() method. doesn't make a difference if I remove the calling of finish()

Comment: Objects dont get deleted if you make a pointer null.

Comment: should I go with removeView for interface objects? or else, what is the best way to destroy an imageView, Animation and MediaPlayer

Comment: Try `animationView.setImageResource(resId);`  so you dont have to make that Drawable.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but unfortunately this did not resolve my issue=/ anything else to suggest here??

Comment: is there any more evidence I can get to see what i causing my application to run out of memory on the second launch?

Comment: there is a chance that android is scaling those 2k+ images every time before showing, so did you try putting images inside drawable-nodpi folder ?

Comment: Have you tried recycling the drawablw once you have done animationView.setImageDrawable(null)? You might try the following in onDestroy(): get the drawable assigned to a local variable; setImageDrawable(null); drawable.recycle()

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library to efficiently load large images.
You can also check [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap) article about how to efficiently load Bitmaps.